# Syntax Error when attempting to /give a player a named diamond sword?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am attempting to give a player a named diamond sword using this command:

```
/give @p diamond_sword 1 0 {display{name:"Burn"}}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Syntax error: Unexpected "{": at "0 {display>>{<<name:"Burn"
```

This happens on both Minecraft Pocket Edition and Minecraft PC. Can someone help me fix this? I really want to know how to use these and I haven't used command blocks untill now.

[image: screenshot showing command and error]

Answer (score 5):

You are missing a colon after display

```
    {display:{name:"Burn"}}
```